# The meaning of the phrase "a dirt lawyer"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

Does anybody know the meaning of a phrase "a dirt lawyer"?
I've got as a part of a homework where I need to describe the meaning of the phrases, but I've never heard this one before and I've searched but found nothing. I hope someone will be able to help

Comment: "i've searched but found nothing"  Really? Using Google.com, I find all the top results are pages that make the meaning clear, with and without quotes around the phrase.  I hadn't heard the phrase before, myself (a native speaker).

Comment: Well sorry, if i had found something i wouldn't have ended up here asking this question, i'm not a native speaker and it is kinda hard for me, and all the top results didn't give me anything

Answer (score 1):

I had to go to a second page of google search to find the actual meaning of the term.

[Linkedin "dirt law"](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-dirt-law-taught-me-curious-connector-tzen-yi-goh)

"I’ve been practicing dirt law for more than 15 years, which means that I help my clients buy, sell, develop, lease and finance real estate."

So, it means law having to do with ground, i.e. "dirt".

Comment: Thanks a lot! You really saved me